# Show that a sequence having a finite limit point cannot approach \infty

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I tried to think how to approach this problem.

Only thing that I can do is to put the finite limit points with  \z_n_1\,  \z_n_2\ , ... \z_n_k\

And then what should I do for the next step?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  If $L$ is a (finite) limit point, then there are infinitely many $n$ for which $|z_n-L|<1$, say.  But that couldn't happen if $z_n\to \infty$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: I think it means by a finite limit point that the limit point is some real less than infinity. Not that there are a finite number of limit points.

Comment: Oh i misunderstood the problem.... sorry

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_n)$ be a real sequence with limit point $x_0 \in \mathbb R$.

Then we have $x_n \in (x_0-1,x_0+1)$ for infinitely many $n$, hence

$(1) \quad x_n <x_0+1$ for infinitely many $n$.

Now suppose that $x_n \to \infty$. Then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ with

$(2) \quad x_n >x_0+1$ for all $n>N$.

But this contradicts $(1)$.